# Armor Stand name is set but not detected by /testfor

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So, I have this command that spawns an armor stand (which should have an name of `player`):

```
summon armor_stand ~ ~1 ~ {ArmorItems:[{id:"minecraft:leather_boots",Count:1b,tag:{display:{color:4673362}},Damage:0s},{id:"minecraft:leather_leggings",Count:1b,tag:{display:{color:3949738}},Damage:0s},{id:"minecraft:leather_chestplate",Count:1b,tag:{display:{color:3847130}},Damage:0s},{id:"minecraft:skull",Count:1b,Damage:3s}],ShowArms:true,NoBasePlate:1b,name:player}
```

But when I spawn it I do this command:

```
 /testfor @e[type=Armor_Stand,name=player] {}
```

And it says it does not find anything. Anyone got an idea what's wrong?

Oh, and

```
 /testfor @e[type=Armor_Stand] {name:"player"}
```

didn't work too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem isn't that it won't detect the name, but that the armor stand doesn't *have* the name. Use {CustomName:"player"} instead of {name:player} when summoning the armor stand and your problem should be fixed.

Comment: Give me a moment to start the game and try it out please.. thanks for the reply anyway!

Comment: No problem my friend. :D